# git squashing multiple commits into multiple commits

Tags: git, version-control, commit

In light of this:

[Combining multiple commits before pushing in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934752/git-combining-multiple-commits-before-pushing)

suppose I have this rebase:

```
pick 16b5fcc msg1
pick c964dea msg3
pick 06cf8ee msg1
pick 396b4a3 msg2
pick 9be7fdb msg3
pick 7dba9cb msg2
```

Suppose I want to combine all comitts with the same message into one...(ie all msg1 commits into a single msg1 commit, all msg2 commits into 1 msg2 commit, etc)

How should I go about squashing these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

git-rebase lets you reorder and squash commits. Something like this ought to work:

```
pick 16b5fcc msg1
squash 06cf8ee msg1
pick 396b4a3 msg2
squash 7dba9cb msg2
pick 9be7fdb msg3
squash c964dea msg3
```

If you have a lot of commits, I would suggest you write a script to group them as above.

Comment: You could also use `fixup` instead of `squash` if you don't want to have to edit every commit message along the way.

Comment: re-ordering commits! that makes me really nervous. I wonder how the actual content of the files will look like, at the end of this kind of `rebase`. Have you actually used this successfully?