# Multiple Commit become 1 commit in git

Tags: git

I created multiple commit in git with multiple comment, i wonder is it possible to make multiple commit into single commit in git, if yes what command we usually use ?

```
pick xxx1 msg1
pick xxx2 msg2
pick xxx3 msg4
pick xxx5 msg5
pick xxx6 msg6
```

i want to change it into 1 commit with 1 comment only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use git merge --squash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git squashing multiple commits into multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146647/git-squashing-multiple-commits-into-multiple-commits)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+squash+multiple+commits

Answer (score 1):

Use `squash` or `fixup` to meld commits together. Fixup throws away the commit message and adds the changes to the previous commit, squash concatenates the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your commit history looks like:

```
X <- A <- B <- C <- D(master)
```

You want to make `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` into only one commit `Y`, like this:

```
X <- Y(master)
```

Make sure you are in a clean state of working dir, then type:

```
git reset X
```

Now the history looks like:

```
X(master)
```

But your working dir is having the content of commit `D`.

Now you can finalize:

```
git add . -Av
git commit -m "just a big message"
```