# Why does Git show my local "pull from remote" when I push my commit to the remote repo?

Tags: git

So I am having a little trouble understanding Git.  I'm using it on Windows, with a remote (GitLab installed) repo.  I have a local copy of the master branch, and I am fairly diligent about using `git pull` frequently to keep my local copy up-to-date.

So it's release time (of course...isn't that when this happens?) and I want to check in the ONE file I've changed.  I type a `git pull` but get an error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        <path>/filename.py
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I use `git diff` and sure enough, another developer fixed a typo in the same spot where I'm trying to commit.  A quick `git status` reveals:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 4 commits, and can be fast-forwarded
```

So, at a loss, I commit my changes to my local repo.

```
git add <filename>
git commit -m "reworking to ignore logs"
```

Now, I can `git pull` successfully.

```
git pull origin master 
...
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy
file1
file2...
....
<filename>
5 files changed, 1 insertion, 63 deletions...
```

Now, I'm able to push my change up to the remote repo

```
git push
```

BUT: here's my question.  On the remote server, it shows BOTH my commit AND the file changes caused by my local `pull` after my commit.  That is to say, it basically shows that the remote files changed, but in fact changed to what wass **ALREADY in** the remote repository.

My boss calls in a panic, asking me why I changed all those (other four) files, and I'm not able to answer.  We end up checking out the two commits (current and pre-my-changes) and diffing them, to prove that it was ONLY my one file's change is what is different, before we both breathe a sigh of relief.

So my question is:  what am I missing?  Why should Git think that I want to see that I changed files to match the remote HEAD, in the remote?  I have seen [this question about `git squash`ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934752/git-combining-multiple-commits-before-pushing), and realize that there is a `git rebase` which may help me, too.  Can someone help me understand why Git does this?  I just feel as though I am not totally embracing the "distributed" paradigm shift.

Comment: It's showing you the history. That's what happened, so that's what it shows. It's not "thinking" anything nefarious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently both you *and* your boss are missing the same thing, and your boss tends towards panic. :-)

Here's what you did, in graphical form drawn as commits.  Originally you had this in your repo:

```
... - F - G    <-- HEAD=master, origin/master
```

where `G` is the then-latest version.  But there's a typo in one file, so you edited that file in your work-tree, fixing the problem.  (I'm going to name the file `typo` just for convenience below.)

```
$ vim typo
...
```

You haven't committed this yet, but you did change it.  Then you did:

```
$ git pull
```

which got you that error message.

Now, behind the scenes, as it were, `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  So let's look at what `git fetch` did.  It seems that other developers made four commits; let's draw them into the graphical representation of the commit-tree:

```
              H - I - J - K      <-- origin/master
            /
... - F - G                      <-- HEAD=master
```

The `git merge` failed because someone else modified file `typo` too.

So, now you do:

```
$ git add typo
$ git commit -m "reworking to ignore logs"
```

This adds a new commit on your current branch (whatever `HEAD` points to), which is obviously `master`.  This gives a commit tree that looks like this:

```
              H - I - J - K      <-- origin/master
            /
... - F - G ------------- L      <-- HEAD=master
```

Now you run `git pull` again, which again is just `fetch` followed by `merge`.  The fetch has nothing to fetch this time (commits `H` through `K`, and the label `origin/master`, are already all taken care of).  The merge then merges commit `K` (`origin/master`) into your current branch, `master`, creating a new merge commit `M`:

```
              H - I - J - K      <-- origin/master
            /               \
... - F - G ------------- L - M  <-- HEAD=master
```

If you now `git push` the result, commit `M` goes in, merging your change, `L`, as the first parent of the merge, and their commit `K` as the second parent.

That's the actual history of what happened to produce `M` (as hobbs noted in comment) and is perfectly normal.  However, you (and your panicky boss) might prefer to construct a different history, that pretends you noticed the problem in `typo` *after* you picked up commits `H` through `K`.  To do that, you'd "rebase" your commit (`L`, above) to sit on top of `origin/master`.

You can do this with `git pull --rebase` (as in [hobbs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19597422/1256452) that appeared while I was typing up this long one), or with plain old `git rebase` after doing a `git fetch`.  In this case, what you will do is make a *copy* of the changes in commit `L` (people often spell this "commit `L'`"):

```
              H - I - J - K - L'
            /
... - F - G ------------- L
```

At this point, you don't need commit `L` any more—it will stick around in the repo for 90 days or so because of git's "reflogs", but it will vanish from normal `git log` output, for instance—so you just need to re-draw this graph a bit, leaving out the line going to `L`, and stick the labels on like so:

```
              H - I - J - K      <-- origin/master
            /               \
... - F - G                   L' <-- HEAD=master
```

and this is exactly what the `git rebase` in the command-sequence:

```
$ git add typo
$ git commit -m "reworking to ignore logs"
$ git rebase
```

would have done.  (Or, again, you can commit and then use `git pull --rebase`, which just makes git use the `fetch`-then-`rebase` sequence, instead of `fetch`-then-`merge`.  If there's nothing to fetch, as in this case, that's the same as just running `git rebase`.)

Answer (score 0):

When you `git pull` on a branch that has local changes, and there are also upstream changes, the pull will merge the upstream changes into your local changes, creating a merge commit. When you push, this merge commit gets sent to the server and becomes part of the history that you see.

Two possible things that could help:

1. Teach your boss to read the history properly and not freak out about changes that don't actually exist.
2. Use `git pull --rebase` on feature branches to pull in upstream changes and rebase your unpushed local work on top of them. This results in a cleaner history, and is generally considered an improvement by everyone except anti-history-rewriting purists.