# How to squash commits after merge branches in Git?

Tags: git, github

I developed a new feature in a **newFeature** branch. And I had merged the branch to master branch before I squash the commits on the **newFeature** branch.

My commits history on **master** branch:
[image]

I had tried command `git rebase -i origin/master`, the file looks different compare to [the example from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934752/combining-multiple-commits-before-pushing-in-git).
According to the answer from the post, it should look similar like the following :

```
pick 16b5fcc Code in, tests not passing
pick c964dea Getting closer
pick 06cf8ee Something changed
pick 396b4a3 Tests pass
pick 9be7fdb Better comments
pick 7dba9cb All done
```

Because in the VIM, I don't see anything look like this at all as you can see in the picture. 
Do I have to manually type the the `pick ...` in the VIM between the `rebase ...`  line and `Commonds:` line?

[image]

I also read the post [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git) in case `git rebase` is not working for me. I am wondering if `git reset --hard` and `git merge --squash` commands can solve my case or not.

**When I do `git log`, I am able to see the commits.**

### Question:

How can I squash the commits from the first commit **aab9e06** to commit **e8abbb0**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, you just need to specify which commit you want to use for the rebase. So in your case it would look like:

```
git rebase -i aab9e06
```

Comment: Why I should rebase `aab9e06`? Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: If you use git rebase -i aab9e06 you'll be left with commit aab9e06 -> xxxxx where xxxxx contains all commits after aab9e06. If you want aab9e06 included in the squashed commit, use git rebase -i aab9e06^ (or manually type in the hash of the commit prior to aab9e06). You need to tell git what commit to leave as is. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase for more info!