# Difference between `git rebase -i master` vs `git rebase -i origin/master`

Tags: git

[Combining multiple commits before pushing in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934752/combining-multiple-commits-before-pushing-in-git)

Based on my understanding, if I use `git rebase -i master`, then later I still need to `git push origin master` to upload the changes.

Question> What is the difference between `rebase -i master` vs `rebase -i origin/master`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we go any further, run:

```
git rev-parse master
```

and:

```
git rev-parse origin/master
```

You'll see two SHA-1s.  If those two SHA-1 values are *the same*, the two rebase commands will *do the same thing*.  If not, they will do *different things*.

#### How the `<upstream>` argument is used

The `<upstream>` argument to `git rebase` has two purposes:

- it selects which commits get rebased, and
- in the absence of an `<onto>` argument, it selects the starting point for the sequence of cherry-picks.

(Remember, the syntax here is `git rebase [options] [<upstream> [<branch>]]` so `master` and `origin/master` in your examples provide an `<upstream>`.  You must use the `--onto` option to provide an `<onto>`, and you're not doing so, so the `<upstream>` provides it instead.)

To see which commits are selected, you can use `git rev-list` (or its more-verbose equivalent, `git log`).  The actual commits selected for rebasing are those that *are* contained in the current branch but *are not* contained in the `<upstream>`.  That is:

```
git rev-list master..HEAD
```

or:

```
git rev-list origin/master..HEAD
```

respectively.  (Replace `rev-list` with `log` to see them in detail, or `log --oneline` to see them as one-line descriptions.)

#### What rebase does

The `rebase` command works by *copying* commits, then setting the branch name to point to the new, tip-most copy.

If you use the interactive version, it puts the commit IDs and instructions into a file that you can edit.  Otherwise it just goes through all the commit IDs from the above `git rev-list` commands, in order.

Before starting the sequence of cherry-picks, `rebase` detaches `HEAD` at the `<onto>` commit.  That is, the `<onto>` commit is the starting point for the copies.

Then, for each commit ID, `rebase` essentially runs `git cherry-pick` (if you're using the interactive version there's no "essentially" about it, it actually uses `git cherry-pick`, with some modifications based on your instruction editing).  This copies the original commit to a new one at the new branch-tip.  As each commit is copied, the new branch grows to contain them all.

Finally, once all the commits are copied, `git rebase` changes the originally-current branch name so that it points to the new tip-most commit on the new branch.

Note that nowhere in this process does git care whether the word `origin` appears in `<upstream>`.  It simply resolves the `<upstream>` argument to its SHA-1 and then runs with that.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you are on branch X and you do `git rebase -i master`, it changes branch X, not master, so you would have to push branch X.

Anyway, if `origin/master` points to the same commit as `master` (i.e. your `master` branch is up to date), then it doesn't matter if you rebase onto one or the other. If they point to different commits, then you will be rebasing onto whatever commit the branch you choose points to.

Answer (score 1):

Means that if you have a V2 and a V3 (Version 2 and Version 3 respectively), you can modify the V2 and with `rebase` it will put the changes in a new version (V4) but merging with V3 (it doesn't matter that is a newer version of it) here is the link where you can see it more explained.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Answer (score 0):

When you use the rebase command you will want to push to origin (the remote host ie GitHub or Bitbucket) either way once it is rebased, but the origin in front of `<branch>` means you are referring to the branch as it is remotely rather than what you have locally on your machine.