# Git: Squash commits in history keeping graph structure

Tags: git

I have a not yet published local repo with graph structure like this:

```
*   G 
*   F
|\
| * E
| * D
* | C: A minor fix -- SQUASHME  
* | B
|/
*   A
```

So I want to squash commits `B` and `C` into a single commit, keeping (I suspect it'll take recreating/rewriting commits to keep) this graph structure with  its branching and merging points.

Any pointers?

Comment: @BjörnKautler Please answer this question so that I may learn something new.

Comment: Hello this link may help you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934752/combining-multiple-commits-before-pushing-in-git

Comment: @AmolUdage The link will not help, as it would remove the branch- and merge-points and create a linear history instead.

Comment: @BjörnKautler Ok I'll check this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git rebase -i A -p
```

then use `fixup` or `squash` stanza for `C`, depending on whether you want to use the commit message of `B` or want to edit it.

*Note:* Without the `-p` parameter the merges will be transformed into linear history.

Comment: Ah, sorry, a local alias to not use `vim` but `jEdit` as editor. I removed it from the answer