# How can I add new changes to the last not-pushed commit?

Tags: git, command-line

- I pulled the last version from the online repository `git pull origin master`
- Then made some changes in the code-base and added them `git add .`
- Then  created a new commit `git commit -m "bug x fixed"`
- Then made some new changes in the code base and I want to merge them to the last commit *(which isn't pushed to the online repository yet)*.

Should I add them again? Should I remove the last commit and make a new one? or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
git add your_changes
git commit --amend
```

The `amend` option will take the last commit and replace it by a new one with the previous changes and the new staged changes (new files, rename, delete...).

It should open the configurated editor with the message of the previous commit, you can replace it with a new message if you like by changing it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just keep committing as many times as you want since this is local. Then at the end, when you are ready, you can "squash" all your local commits into a single commit that is pushed up to the remote. There are a few ways to do this, but here is a link with a nice example (possibly one of the more flexible/easy ways): [see top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934752/combining-multiple-commits-before-pushing-in-git)

The advantage of this over things like "amend" is that you can keep all your commits and history locally so you have a better changes of going back if things go wrong or doing smaller diff etc...  and all the hassle of going back and amending things later can be postponed to one time only all at the end when you are good and ready.... well, I prefer it that way anyway :)