# How to squash a selection of commits

Tags: git

How do I squash 2, 3 and 4 into a single commit?

1. last commit
2. last commit -1
3. last commit -2
4. last commit -3
5. last commit -4

Comment: Interactive rebase?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining multiple commits before pushing in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934752/combining-multiple-commits-before-pushing-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+combine+commits

Answer (score 0):

Interactive rebase as told by matt, or this way, with no interactive stuff:

```
git checkout commit2
git reset --soft commit5
git commit -m "Here's the squash"
git cherry-pick commit1
```

Done!