# git combine two consecutive commits

Tags: git

I have the following commits in my branch.

4. last commit
5. third commit
6. second commit
7. first commit

How could I combine commit 3 and 2 but with commit message of commit 2. This is the result I will be expecting

4. last commit
5. second commit (3 is combined to 2)
6. first commit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining multiple commits before pushing in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934752/combining-multiple-commits-before-pushing-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+combine+commits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do this interactively using

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

then you will see an editor like

```
pick <sha-1> commit 1
pick <sha-2> commit 2
pick <sha-3> commit 3
pick <sha-4> commit 4
```

which you need to change to:

```
pick <sha-1> commit 1
pick <sha-2> commit 2
fixup <sha-3> commit 3
pick <sha-4> commit 4
```

save and quit, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

- `git rebase -i <sha key of first commit>`
- An editor will be opened. Change `pick` to `squash` at second and third commit
- Write and quit
- The editor will pop up again for you to write the new commit message.

Comment: 1. no need to run git commit after "write and quit".
2. fixup does automatically what he wants, why complicating things with squash.
3. what does your answer add to mine?

Comment: Thank you for pointing these up. It's an alternative answer. Your answer is pointing `fix`, mine is `squash`.

Comment: Fair enough, although it is more compliated. Still your answer is wrong since there is no need to run `git commit`after "write and quit".

Comment: Yep I remembered that way but was unable to try it first. I'm investigating it.

Comment: @Chris fixup does not "combine" the commits, only readies it for `autosquash` (you can add that to your rebase line with `--autosquash`). I would go with this solution but for no particular reason. There is no extra overhead whatsoever, simply a "s" where you put a "fixup". Perhaps if you prefer not combining the commit messages fixup is a better option marginally. Of course if you want it then squash is the only option.

Comment: @kabanus you are mixing up "fixup commits" and the "fixup" directive when rebasing interactively. From the help in the editor: **f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message**

Comment: @emremrah `Change pick to squash at second and third commit` This will squash 1, 2 & 3. OP wants to squash only 2 & 3.