# Combining Multiple Commits Into One Commit

Tags: git

I have a branch named **code-clean-and-proper-commenting** there is 120 commit in this branch, I have pushed this branch on my upstream, Now I have to combine that 120 commits into one single commit and I have to re pushed the changes into my upstream's **code-clean-and-proper-commenting** branch.

How do I do this things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining Multiple Commits Into One Prior To Push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721566/combining-multiple-commits-into-one-prior-to-push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you rebasing your branch can fix your problem.You can read more about rebasing from [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing). On the top of your branch you can do :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~120
```

Where -i option is for interactive rebasing. You edit the commit history in any way you want. And after that you can force push to your upstream server

```
git push origin code-clean-and-proper-commenting -f
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Rohan Kumar
and here is also a simple solution-
http://ndlib.github.io/practices/one-commit-per-pull-request/

Comment: found another best solution:
http://ndlib.github.io/practices/one-commit-per-pull-request/