# Is git push --force-with-lease always safe?

Tags: git

I've always followed the rule not to modify the git history once it has been pushed to a remote repository.

But I am wondering if interactive rebasing into a push --force-with-lease bypasses this rule?

Is it perfectly safe for other users if the force-with-lease succeeds or are there any caveats to this strategy?

Thank you in advance for any input.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would like to describe a plausible case where the `--force-with-lease` does not save you from overwriting your colleagues work.

### It all begins with Bob

doing the following while having an up-to-date master branch checked out:

```
# Creating a new branch called feature/one
$ git checkout -b feature/one

# Do some changes and git add ...
$ git commit

# Push for the first time
$ git push --set-upstream origin feature/one

# Checkout another branch to work on something else
```

Situation on Bob's machine

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             o--o   <-- feature/one
```

### Alice continues

Alice picks up the work on feature/one and commits stuff on top of Bob's work and pushes her changes, in the mean
time some unrelated pull requests are merged to the master branch.
How Alice's working tree looks like

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
           \
            o--o--x--x   <-- feature/one
```

### Bob continues

Bob is tasked to rebase Alices work on the current master branch, and does the following

1. `git pull` while he is on the master branch, which basically is a `git fetch` and a `git merge`
    The consequences of this step are important later.

   Situation on Bob's machine:

   ```
   ...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
               \
                o--o   <-- feature/one
   ```

   ```
   ...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- origin/master (HEAD)
               \
                o--o--x--x   <-- origin/feature/one
   ```

   Bob's machine now contains an up-to-date remote but changes in origin/feature/one are not yet merged to
    feature/one.
2. Bob checks out  the branch with `git checkout feature/one`
3. Bob forgets to do a `git pull`
4. Bob rebases his local branch on the master with `git rebase -i origin/master`

   the situation on bobs machine looks like this:

   ```
   ...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
                     \
                      o--o   <-- feature/one
   ```
5. Bob thinks that he succsessfully rebased his branch and force pushes `feature/one` to `origin/feature/one`, because
    Bob is a nice guy, he pushes with `git push --force-with-lease origin feature/one` and expects that the option
    `--force-with-lease` will prevent his push operation, if he is about to overwrite other peoples work.
    **But the option will not save him**, if I understand
    [this blog post](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/) correctly, `--force-with-lease` sees no
    difference between origin/feature/one on Bob's machine and the the actual origin/feature/one and therefore assumes
    that Bob's working tree will not overwrite anything on the remote if forced pushed to it. The reason for the lack
    of difference, lies in the excution of an implicit `git fetch` as part of `git pull` earlier (in step 1 of this
    section) on a different branch.

   After the push, the remote will look like this

   ```
   ...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
                     \
                      o--o   <-- feature/one
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   ...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
                     \
                      o--o--x--x   <-- feature/one
   ```

   Here is the relevant part of the blog postl linked above:

   > The fetch will pull the objects and refs from the remote, but without a matching merge does not update the working
   >   tree. This will make it look as if the working copy of the remote is up to date with the remote without actually
   >   including the new work, and trick `--force-with-lease` into overwriting the remote branch

Comment: Thank you for an example, I just tested this and can confirm that Alice's commits x-x  are lost even when using --force-with-lease.

Comment: Very happy to hear you actually did the work to confirm it. I tried the example only once.

Comment: If Bob ever did a `git status` on `feature/one` branch after pulled on master, he would see his branch is behind.

Comment: I told Bob he should pay more attention to the status of his repo.

Comment: Good explanation. I'm still missing why the x--x commits would be lost, though, if `git push --force-with-lease` is used. My understanding is it would fail, which is the safety part.

Comment: force-with-lease will only checks if bobs origin/feature/one and the origin/feature/one on the remote differ from each other. Unaware that bob rebases his feature/one on the master branch and pushes. You could do an experiment and prove me wrong. I would actually be thanksful if you take the time to verify by experiment.

Answer (score 16):

It can be made safer with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021): "[`git push --force-with-lease[=<ref>]`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/de0a7effc86aadf6177fdcea52b5ae24c7a85911/Documentation/git-push.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup>" can easily be misused to lose commits unless the user takes good care of their own "`git fetch`".

A new option "`--force-if-includes`" attempts to ensure that what is being force-pushed was created after examining the commit at the tip of the remote ref that is about to be force-replaced.

It rejects a forced update of a branch when its remote-tracking ref has updates that we do not have locally.

See [commit 3b5bf96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b5bf96573b5773e64f7884607794c268b352992), [commit 3b990aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b990aa645d1169b7373d12cbf1511ca4633e349), [commit 99a1f9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99a1f9ae10816c2527d7197a5dde714f980b712b) (03 Oct 2020) by [Srinidhi Kaushik (`clickyotomy`)](https://github.com/clickyotomy).
See [commit aed0800](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aed0800ca68806a7bc1dc15995417b9171f22079) (02 Oct 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit de0a7ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de0a7effc86aadf6177fdcea52b5ae24c7a85911), 27 Oct 2020)</sup>

> ### [`push`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99a1f9ae10816c2527d7197a5dde714f980b712b): add reflog check for "`--force-if-includes`"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Srinidhi Kaushik</sup>

> Add a check to verify if the remote-tracking ref of the local branch is reachable from one of its "reflog" entries.
>
> The check iterates through the local ref's reflog to see if there is an entry for the remote-tracking ref and collecting any commits that are seen, into a list; the iteration stops if an entry in the reflog matches the remote ref or if the entry timestamp is older the latest entry of the remote ref's "reflog". If there wasn't an entry found for the remote ref, `"in_merge_bases_many()`" is called to check if it is reachable from the list of collected commits.
>
> When a local branch that is based on a remote ref, has been rewound and is to be force pushed on the remote, "`--force-if-includes`" runs a check that ensures any updates to the remote-tracking ref that may have happened (by push from another repository) in-between the time of the last update to the local branch (via "`git pull`", for instance) and right before the time of push, have been integrated locally before allowing a forced update.
>
> If the new option is passed without specifying "`--force-with-lease`", or specified along with "`--force-with-lease=<refname>:<expect>`" it is a "no-op".

Answer (score 5):

It is **not safe**.

See [this atlassian blog post](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/), which describes that `git push --force-with-lease` is safer than `git push -f`. However, it partically overwrites the remote making it not safe.

> But --force has a lesser-known sibling that partially protects against damaging forced updates; this is --force-with-lease.

The difference is that `--force-with-lease` does an additional check and aborts if the remote contains work your local repository does not know about. But it still overwrites the remote branch resulting the same problems as `-f`, it just doesn't do that if someone else pushed in the meantime.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks! Is it safe if I don't perform a fetch then?

Comment: You mean, after executing `git push --force-with-lease`?

Comment: As far as I know, you can always fetch. The problem is when you pull/merge the fetched branch.

Comment: If force-with-lease succeeds and I don't have to execute a fetch.

Comment: I think you would have to. It still overwrites your repository.

Comment: Thank you for that link. It explains simply and understandably that `git push --force-with-lease` will verify the remote repository reference is that same as it is locally or it will fail the `git push --force`. If it fails, you know you need to pull, which is not foolproof but definitely safer.

Answer (score 3):

> I've always followed the rule to not modify commits that has been pushed to a remote repository.

It is not possible to modify commits.  It does not matter whether they have been sent to another repository or not: you cannot change any existing commit.

That's not what you're doing with `git push -f` either, though.  This still does not modify existing commits!  What this does is tell the other Git—the one receiving the push—that it should change a *name*, even if the change to the *name* would "lose" some commit(s).

The key concept here is *reachability*.  See [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) to learn all about reachability.  The short version, though, is this: each Git commit has a "true name" that is its raw hash ID.  Each Git commit also contains the raw hash ID of some set of *earlier* commits.<sup>1</sup>  We say that this commit *points to* the earlier commit(s).  Meanwhile, a *name*—like a branch name—points to (contains the hash ID of) exactly one commit: specifically, the *last* commit that is to be considered "contained in the branch".

So we can draw this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

where the uppercase letters stand in for the big ugly hash IDs.  If `H` is the *last* commit in a branch like `master`, the name `master` points to `H`.  Meanwhile `H` contains the hash ID of its parent commit `G`, so `H` points to `G`.  `G` contains the hash ID of its parent `F`, and so on, all the way back to the very first commit.

While the internal arrows all point backwards like this, it's easier to draw them as connecting lines in StackOverflow postings, so I'm going to do that now.  Let's look at how we add a *new* commit to `master`.  We run:

```
git checkout master
# ... do some work, run `git add` ...
git commit
```

The `git checkout` step attaches the special name `HEAD` to the branch name, so that Git knows which branch name to update, in case we have more than one branch name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             o--o   <-- develop
```

for example.  We do the work and make a new commit, which we'll call `I`.  Git writes out commit `I`, makes it point back to commit `H`—the one we *were* using up until we made `I`—and then makes the name `master` point to new commit `I`:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Now suppose we `git push` this update to some *other* repository.  That other repository has *its own* branch names, independent of ours, but we were totally in sync with that other repository when we started: it had the same commits, with the same hash IDs, up through `H`.  So we sent the other Git our commit `I`, and then asked them: *Other Git at `origin`, please, if it's OK, make your `master` name point to commit `I`.*  They say OK, and now *they* have *their* master pointing to this new commit `I` too, and we're all in sync again.

But now we realize: gah, we made a mistake!  We'd like to stop using `I` and make a new and improved commit `J` instead!  Maybe the mistake was as simple as a typo in the commit message, or maybe we have to fix a file and `git add` it first, but eventually we run:

```
git commit --amend
```

Despite the name of the flag, this *doesn't change any existing commit*.  It can't!  What it does is make a totally *new* commit `J`.  But instead of making `J` point back to `I`, it makes `J` point to `I`'s *parent* `H`:

```
             J   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H--I   [abandoned]
```

Commit `I` *can no longer be found* in our repository, because the *name* we used to find it—`master`—doesn't find it any more.  The name now finds commit `J`.  From `J`, we step back to `H`.  It seems as if we've changed commit `I`.  We haven't, though, and in fact it's still there in our repository, and—if we haven't fiddled with any of the configuration knobs in Git—it will *stay* there for at least 30 days, because there are some semi-secret names<sup>2</sup> by which we *can* find `I`'s hash ID, and thus view commit `I` again after all.

---

<sup>1</sup>These *have* to be earlier / older commits:

- To put the hash ID of some commit into some new commit you're making, the hash ID of that other commit must exist.  (Git won't let you use the hash ID of a commit that doesn't exist.)  So these are existing commits, in this commit you propose making now.
- Git then makes the new commit and assigns it a new and unique hash ID: one that has never occurred before.  This new commit, now that it is made, *cannot be changed*.  Indeed, **no commit can ever change**.  So the hash IDs inside each new commit are those of older commits.

As a result, commits always point *backwards*, to earlier commits.  Git therefore works backwards.

<sup>2</sup>These are mostly in Git's *reflogs*.  For some operations that move branch names, Git stores the hash ID temporarily in another special name `ORIG_HEAD` as well.  This name gets overwritten by the *next* operation that saves a hash ID in `ORIG_HEAD`, but `ORIG_HEAD` is particularly useful right after a failed `git rebase`, for instance.

---

#### This is where `--force` comes in

We now have this:

```
             J   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H--I   [abandoned]
```

in our own repository.  We'd like the *other* Git repository—the one over at `origin`—to have this too.  But if we run `git push`, our Git calls up their Git, sends over commit `J`, and then says: *Please, if it's OK, make your `master` name point to commit `J`.*  If they do that, *they* will "lose" commit `I` too!  They are finding `I` through *their* name `master`; if they move their `master` to point to `J`, they won't be able to find `I`.<sup>3</sup>

In the end, then, they'll just say *no, I won't do that*.  Your Git shows you the `rejected` message:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast forward)
```

telling you that *they* refuse to set *their* `master` the same way that you have your `master` set, because they'd lose some commits (that's the "non-fast-forward" part).

To overcome that, you can send a forceful command: *Set your `master`!*  They may or may not obey, but if they don't obey, it's no longer because they'll lose commits: the "force" option says to do it even if they will lose commits as a result.

The drawback here is: what if someone *else* has built *another* new commit atop your commit `I`, while you were fixing your `I` with your replacement `J`?  Then *their* Git—the one over at `origin`—actually has:

```
 ...--F--G--H--I--K   <-- master
```

If you use `git push --force` to tell them to set their `master` to `J`, they'll end up with:

```
              J   <-- master
             /
 ...--F--G--H--I--K   [abandoned]
```

and the abandoned commits include not only your `I` (which you wanted gone) but someone else's `K` too.

#### Enter `--force-with-lease`

What `--force-with-lease` does is to use *your* Git's memory of *their* Git's `master`.  Note that when you run `git fetch` to get commits *from* them, your Git stores, in its own storage-areas, *their* branch names, modified to have `origin/` in front of them and to become your *remote-tracking names*.  So in your own Git you actually have this:

```
             J   <-- master (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/master
```

Your `origin/master` remembers that *their* `master` remembers commit `I`.

When you use `git push --force-with-lease`, your Git calls up their Git, sends commit `J` as usual.  This time, though, instead of either *Please set your `master` to `J` if it's OK* or *Set your `master` to J!*, your Git sends a request of the form:

*I think your `master` points to `I`.  If so, forcefully move it to point to `J` instead.*

This introduces a new way to reject the operation.  If their `master` now points to `K`, they'll still say *no*.  But if their `master` still points to `I`—the commit you *want* them to abandon—they will probably obey the forceful push and make their `master` point to `J`.

If they do obey, your Git updates your own `origin/master` to point to `J` too.  This maintains the property that your `origin/*` names remember, to the best of your Git's ability, where *their* Git's branch names point.  But this can get stale, so you may need to run `git fetch origin` (or just `git fetch`) to update your remote-tracking names.  How often you need to run `git fetch` depends on how fast *their* Git updates.

Of course, if you *do* run `git fetch`, you'd best check to see if your `origin/master` still points where you thought!  Pay attention to the output from `git fetch`: it tells you if your Git has updated your own `origin/master`.  If their `master` has moved, someone else has fiddled with *their* commits, and you might need to know this.

---

<sup>3</sup>Server Gits generally *don't* have reflogs enabled, so they'll garbage collect abandoned commits a lot sooner than our own local clones, too.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that mistake in the first sentence. I have edited it now, hopefully the question is more accurate.