# Can I force-push on a branch which only I work on?

Tags: git, git-push

I know in Git it's bad practice to `push --force`. My understanding is that `push --force-with-lease` is safe.

With that in mind, I have a question with three variants.

1. Is it bad practice to `push --force-with-lease` on a branch on which only I add commits and for which there is no Merge Request open?
2. Is it bad practice if there is a Merge Request open for the branch?
3. Is it bad practice if I know someone pulled it to review it locally?

If yes, could you please argument why? What are the practical implications that make this a bad practice, if they do?

In my mind, if it's clear to everyone that only I push to the branch, the only difference it makes to everybody else is that, after `git fetch origin my-branch` and `git checkout my-branch`, they have to `git reset --hard origin/my-branch` instead of `git merge`, which is slightly longer.

What pieces of the puzzle am I missing, if any?

Comment: Actually, force pushing to a feature branch on which _only_ you work is not bad practice at all.

Comment: `--force-with-lease` is safe**r**, not safe - it's still not generally a good thing to do on a shared branch.

Comment: If you work in different repository copies, like one at home and another at work, or like one at `/path/to/foo` and another at `/path/to/bar`, it can be considered that two or more persons are maintaining the same branch. It's still possible you overwrite and lose your own data. It's okay if you know the consequences of force push. But it's not suggested to use it in any case even if you are the only maintainer.

Comment: The way I like to put it is that for any branch name where you will use force-push, you *and all other users of this branch* must *agree* that force-pushes happen to this branch name. If you are the only user, you must agree with **yourself**. For most people, that's probably not too difficult or onerous. (Perhaps the multiple-personality types might have issues here. )

Comment: @jonrsharpe I could agree, depending on the meaning of shared branch. If I am the only writer and everyone else is a reader, do you consider that a shared branch? If so, why would you consider it not a good idea? It's the same issue I have with the golden rule of rebasing: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing#the-golden-rule-of-rebasing : what is a "public" branch?

Answer (score 3):

The reason people generally recommend against force pushing is because for many branches, especially the main branches in a repository, people expect updating the branch to always be a fast-forward merge.

If only you are working on the branch, then there's no problem with force-pushing, whether you do it with `--force-with-lease` or not, because you're not modifying anyone's expectations.  Nobody else is worse off because you did that.

If you do decide to force-push, it's a matter of communicating expectations.  If you have a merge request open, then sometimes it can be hard for people to re-review when you've force pushed, and so you may wish to avoid it.  What I typically do in such a case is to add fixup or squash commits with `git commit --fixup` or `git commit --squash` and then, after the reviewer has approved, squash them down.

Regardless, if you communicate effectively with your teammmates or other contributors and let them know that you've force-pushed, then it's likely to be less of a problem.  In an open-source project where you can't always have that communication, then it typically is better to avoid it when possible.

Comment: So... communication is indeed the missing piece, as I suggested?

Comment: I think we're in agreement on that, but our answers explain it a bit differently.

Comment: Indeed. I don't use fixup or squash enough myself, good advice there.

Answer (score 1):

[`git push --force-with-lease`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937476/6309) is safer, and you also have [`git push --force-if-includes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627761/6309) (Git 2.30+), which attempts to ensure that what is being force-pushed was created *after* examining the commit at the tip of the remote ref that is about to be force-replaced.

But in both instance, this is a communication issue.
(communication between team members being the main piece missing here)

The rule I follow for merging an MR is to *reject* it if the merge is not a fast-forward one.
Which means the requested must rebase the MR branch on top of the new target branch HEAD before re-applying for the MR to be merged.

Of course, if I force push to a branch being the source of a MR (as opposed to the target), there is no problem, and the MR would be automatically updated.