# Git merge first or git push first?

Tags: git

which one is the best way?

On develop branch:

**1)**

- git checkout -b feature
- git add .
- git commit -m "done"
- git checkout develop
- git pull origin develop
- git merge --no-ff feature
- *resolve conflicts*
- git push origin develop
- *code review*

**2)**

- git checkout -b feature
- git add .
- git commit -m "done"
- git push origin feature
- *code review*
- *resolve conflicts*
- git merge > to develop

Comment: We currently rebase with main until we merge into main. Making the flow `git checkout -b new`, work work... `git rebase --onto origin/main $(git log --merges -1 --format=%h)`, ... and then finally merge it into main with a merge commit.

Answer (score 1):

A code review is not supposed to take place on the target branch (in your case "`develop`"), only on the source branch, *rebased* first on top of the target branch.

The idea of a code review is to allow the final merge only if the CR passes.
If the review rejects the commit, no merge.

So:

```bash
git fetch
git switch feature
git rebase origin/develop
# resolve conflicts, test everything
git push --force-if-includes 
# request a review before merge, through for instance a pull request
```

(On `--force-if-includes`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627761/6309))

If you are several to work on `feature` branch, do communicate when you rebase the branch, as it will change its history, and your colleagues will have to reset their local `feature` branch to the new `origin/feature` forced pushed one.